# Trying to write a regex to get the version details from the 3.0.0.10240-8423651

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am trying to write the regex to fetch just the version details. It seems like I am missing something in the regex. Appreciate your help.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class VersionValidator {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     // This should print the "3.0.0.10240"
    System.out.println(getVersion("3.0.0.10240-8423651"));
    
    // This should print the "3.0.0.10240"
    System.out.println(getVersion("3.0.0.10240"));
    
    // This should print the "3.0.0"
    System.out.println(getVersion("3.0.0-8423651"));
  }

  /**
  *
  * 3.0.0.10240-8423651 -> 3.0.0.10240
  * 
  * 3.0.0.10240 -> 3.0.0.10240
  * 
  * 3.0.0-8423651 -> 3.0.0
  * 
  */
  public static String getVersion(String version) {
    Pattern vp = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d)(\\.\\d+)?(-\\d+)?");
    Matcher vm = vp.matcher(version);
    if (vm.matches()) {
        return vm.group(1);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your pattern already matches, and you have 3 capturing groups. In your code you are only returning group 1, but you could check for group 2 and concatenate it with group 1. See https://regex101.com/r/ftOWab/1

Comment: srinij - What @Thefourthbird is suggesting you is, to `return vm.group(1) + vm.group(2);` instead of `return vm.group(1);` if you do not want to change your regex.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you are just after whatever is in front of the - if it is present.

i.e.

```
String pattern = "^([\.0-9]+)(?:-[0-9]+)?$";
```

Comment: The pattern could possibly also match only dots.

Comment: And that's a problem because?

Comment: It is not a problem but a mere note. The OP's pattern is quite specific `\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d` and using a character class makes it pattern with a broader match. You don't have to escape the dot in the character class.

Comment: OP's data source is also quite specific.  Sure you can tighten the pattern, but if the data source will always be from the method and the desired result is everything before the - if it is present, then why bother?

Answer (score 1):

The regex for your requirement is `(?<![^\d])\b(?:\d[\d.]*)`

Check [this](https://regex101.com/r/VthavK/2) for a demo and explanation.

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. Negative Lookbehind `(?<![^\d])`
2. `\b` is used for word boundary
3. Non-capturing group `(?:\d[\d.]*)`

Check [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to learn more about these patterns. You may also like to check [Regular Expressions Tutorials by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).

Apart from the regex, another problem in your code is using [`Matcher#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) instead of [`Matcher#find`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()).

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getVersion("3.0.0.10240-8423651"));
    }

    public static String getVersion(String version) {
        Pattern vp = Pattern.compile("(?<![^\\d])\\b(?:\\d[\\d.]*)");
        Matcher vm = vp.matcher(version);
        if (vm.find()) {
            return vm.group();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
3.0.0.10240
```

Comment: You can omit the non capturing group `(?:...)` and it could possibly also match `3...`

Comment: @Thefourthbird - Thanks for reviewing it. I've put `?:` purposefully because I didn't want to make that group a capturing group. I would have to use `group(1)` instead of just `group()` after removing `?:` which I didn't want to do. Thanks again for taking some time out and putting helpful comments on some of my answers. I'm sure, your comment and this clarification will be useful for future visitors of this page.